# How to know which validation fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Yesterday I was working on an interface which was developed by another developer. On this interface I was facing a problem that when I clicked on the update button it was not performing any action because of the client side validation (like `RequiredFieldValidator` or `RegularExpressionValidator` etc.) and there was no message regarding that which validation fails.

I do not know the coding of this page, so one solution was that I should remove the validators one by one or can give the error message to all the validations.

My question is: is there any way to find out which validation fails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it asp.net or asp.mvc? what's the file extension? aspx or cshtml?

Comment: Thanks for your response -it is aspx page

Comment: post the page code related the update button you mentioned

Comment: Just guessing : If you are using an MVC application and it fails in `ModelState.IsValid`, then try capturing the error may be like `var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).ToList();`

Comment: That is not MVC and there must be any solution with the help of the F12 because all the client side code can be checked here, so please help me in this regard or any other solution and i can not post the page code here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelState.Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate_properties%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

MSDN : Returns a ValueProviderResult object that encapsulates the value that was being bound during model binding.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // You can see here reason for fail
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors); 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is not MVC, i have just used the simple page aspx page with with a update button and when i click on the button then it does not go to the server side code because of the client validation has been failed.